# Powershell scrip to run a query in multiple servers

Tags: powershell

Trying to run the following query in multiple databases but receiving the following error : Invoke-SqlCmd : Value cannot be null.

```
 $query = @' SQL SCRIPT ' @
 $csvFilePath = 'PATH FOR CSV FILE'
 $serverlist = echo (list of servers ) 

  $queryresults = $null
  $InvokeParams = @{ 
   SERVER = $serverlist
   Database = 'TEST DATABASE'
   Username = 'username '
   Password = 'password1'
   Query = $query
   QueryTimeout = 100

   }

  foreach($server in $serverlist)
{
   write-host "Executing query against server: " $server
   $queryResults = Invoke-SqlCmd @InvokeParams -Erroraction stop 

}

 write-host "Saving Query Results in CSV format..."
$queryResults | export-csv  $csvFilePath   -NoTypeInformation
write-host "Converting CSV output to Excel..."
```

Do I always have to specify parameters ? What if my query is about creating a table for example ?

Comment: When you call Invoke-SQLCMD with @InvokeParams, should that be $InvokeParams? I'm not sure why you have it that way. The error is literally saying "You're telling me to use Invoke-SQLCMD, but you're not giving me any data"

Comment: @Clev Using the @ is the proper way with [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-5.1) to supply parameters in a hash table.

Comment: Move the `$InvokeParams=@{` inside the foreach and set `Server = $server`. Also the [here string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-5.1)  `$query` will return an error due to wrong format.

Comment: what do you mean by wrong format ??

Comment: @LotPings script is only grabbing info from one server ? any reason ?

Comment: For wrong format read the supplied link. For database **I** don't know what your unknown SQL script does.

Comment: its working now, but i was wondering if as an output to excel, possible to add a empty row to split them apart , each server. For example: server 1 = results   EMPTY ROW  server2 = results  Empty ROW